# Are my HTML5 semantics correct?

Tags: html

My questions are:

1. I'm I using the HTML5 header, footer, nav, article and aside tags correctly?
2. I'm I over using the div tag?

Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>
        Simple Blog!
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="simple_blog.css" />
</head>
<body>

<!-- Menu navigation -->
<div id="header">
<nav id="centerDiv">
    <ul class="centerUL">
        <li id="blog"><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        <li id="projects"><a href="">Projects</a></li>
        <li id="about"><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
<nav>
</div>

<!-- Main content -->
<div id="column-holder">
<div id="main-content">

<article>
    <header>
        <h1>Main Content!</h1>
        <p>Published date</p>
    </header>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pharetra aliquam dolor non egestas. Mauris nec urna et tellus sodales pellentesque. Duis consequat porta urna eu sagittis. Nulla rhoncus, eros nec feugiat iaculis, tortor nibh molestie metus, nec fringilla augue lectus non justo. Nullam id tellus magna. Phasellus sit amet mi felis. Donec tempor cursus dignissim.</p>

    <p>Nunc semper enim vitae sem fringilla quis scelerisque tortor mollis. Vivamus ac nibh vitae ipsum adipiscing rutrum sit amet scelerisque dui. Curabitur interdum enim vitae nibh sollicitudin consectetur. Fusce venenatis, diam eu accumsan hendrerit, justo nisi egestas leo, ac vehicula sapien velit et mi. Mauris vehicula metus non lacus sodales feugiat. Praesent felis magna, interdum in consectetur vel, imperdiet vitae libero. Curabitur sed neque non enim eleifend pharetra ac a ante. Phasellus viverra auctor nulla, vitae placerat felis semper at. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi risus felis, vehicula id pharetra sed, fermentum nec ligula. Maecenas pulvinar tristique quam, sed porttitor ligula ullamcorper eget. Aliquam at felis ante, sit amet faucibus nibh. Aliquam metus ante, ultrices quis dapibus non, placerat et mauris. Donec at ligula dolor. Phasellus non orci arcu.</p>

    <p>Mauris ut mi ipsum, eget rutrum nibh. Nulla et arcu in diam tristique ultricies eget non lectus. Praesent sit amet leo nisl, in suscipit metus. Mauris sapien eros, lobortis vel lacinia id, pretium sit amet tortor. Aliquam pretium mollis erat, aliquet fermentum velit placerat dictum. Nullam mattis convallis molestie. Aenean ullamcorper faucibus congue. Sed sem erat, bibendum id pulvinar ac, rhoncus sed velit. In posuere erat sit amet leo volutpat eleifend. Ut a odio sit amet nisl viverra euismod.</p> 
    <footer>
        <p><small>Creative Commons...</small></p>
    </footer>   
</article>  
</div>

<!-- Side article -->
<aside>
    <div id="sidebar">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pharetra aliquam dolor non egestas. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pharetra aliquam dolor non egestas. </p>    
</aside>


</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you only miss the `<section>` usage (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/section). Also `<header>` usage seems to be wrong; it should be "the" header if remember correctly and not inside other blocks. More info on this wonderful MDN page; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/HTML5.

Comment: +1 <section> ok, thanks for the link, I'll read it now

Comment: I also suspect I'm abusing the use of <div>

Comment: Don't really worry too much. What you have now is already a lot times better than the average website I come across. These days; search engines are highly optimized to detect sections of the website for themselves :) There's nothing wrong with the `<div>`s; theyre just neutral blocks.

Comment: This is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Allendar: `<header>` can be used anywhere where a section header is appropriate, so its use here as an article header is acceptable. It does not have to be "the" page header only - although in this case the element `<div id="header">` should of course be replaced with `<header>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not bad, but there are a few things to improve to make it more semantical.

```
<div id="header">
<nav id="centerDiv">
    ...
<nav>
</div>
```

`nav` on its own is a block element. No need to nest it in another div there. I would probably put the navigation inside a global `header` tag, as the navigation is—probably—part of the site’s navigation. A logo or something would go in there as well.

```
<div id="column-holder">
<div id="main-content">

<article>
    ...
</article>  
</div>
```

Using one div to mark your “main” area is generally fine. You should give it the simpler id `main` though. Even better would be using the [`main`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-main-element) tag, which also comes with the semantic roles necessary.

Apart from that, I don’t think that `column-holder` div should be there.

```
<footer>
    <p><small>Creative Commons...</small></p>
</footer>
```

If you just nest multiple things like that, it’s already a sign that you are not doing it that well. `footer` can hold text directly, so you could just do `<footer>Creative Commons...</footer>` if it’s just a short text. If you have a bit more to display there, additional paragraphs are fine. The styling shouldn’t happen through a `small` tag though (style the whole footer via css).

```
<aside>
    <div id="sidebar">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>    
</aside>
```

The div wasn’t closed. Also the same as above with the header: no need to further nest it in a div. The `aside` can already do that job.

Answer (score 1):

I would build just such a scheme.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>
        Simple Blog!
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="simple_blog.css" />
</head>
<body>

<!-- Menu navigation -->
<header>
 <nav class="centerUL">   
    <ul>
        <li id="blog"><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        <li id="projects"><a href="">Projects</a></li>
        <li id="about"><a href="">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>

<!-- Main content -->
<section  id="wrapper">
<article >
        <h1>Main Content!</h1>
        <p>Published date</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pharetra aliquam dolor non egestas. Mauris nec urna et tellus sodales pellentesque. Duis consequat porta urna eu sagittis. Nulla rhoncus, eros nec feugiat iaculis, tortor nibh molestie metus, nec fringilla augue lectus non justo. Nullam id tellus magna. Phasellus sit amet mi felis. Donec tempor cursus dignissim.</p>

    <p>Nunc semper enim vitae sem fringilla quis scelerisque tortor mollis. Vivamus ac nibh vitae ipsum adipiscing rutrum sit amet scelerisque dui. Curabitur interdum enim vitae nibh sollicitudin consectetur. Fusce venenatis, diam eu accumsan hendrerit, justo nisi egestas leo, ac vehicula sapien velit et mi. Mauris vehicula metus non lacus sodales feugiat. Praesent felis magna, interdum in consectetur vel, imperdiet vitae libero. Curabitur sed neque non enim eleifend pharetra ac a ante. Phasellus viverra auctor nulla, vitae placerat felis semper at. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi risus felis, vehicula id pharetra sed, fermentum nec ligula. Maecenas pulvinar tristique quam, sed porttitor ligula ullamcorper eget. Aliquam at felis ante, sit amet faucibus nibh. Aliquam metus ante, ultrices quis dapibus non, placerat et mauris. Donec at ligula dolor. Phasellus non orci arcu.</p>

    <p>Mauris ut mi ipsum, eget rutrum nibh. Nulla et arcu in diam tristique ultricies eget non lectus. Praesent sit amet leo nisl, in suscipit metus. Mauris sapien eros, lobortis vel lacinia id, pretium sit amet tortor. Aliquam pretium mollis erat, aliquet fermentum velit placerat dictum. Nullam mattis convallis molestie. Aenean ullamcorper faucibus congue. Sed sem erat, bibendum id pulvinar ac, rhoncus sed velit. In posuere erat sit amet leo volutpat eleifend. Ut a odio sit amet nisl viverra euismod.</p> 

</article>  
<!-- Side article -->
<aside id="sidebar">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pharetra aliquam dolor non egestas. </p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque pharetra aliquam dolor non egestas. </p>    
</aside>
</section>
<footer>
    <p><small>Creative Commons...</small></p>
</footer> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 Yes this is much better than what I had. I like how you used the id tags in nav, section, aside, etc. Yes I will do this from now on. Thanks

Comment: @Anthony As a small *aside*: Divs are not evil ;) It’s okay to use them when there isn’t a better tag :)